# Opening and checking a Pem file in SWI-Prolog

Tags: ssl, prolog, swi-prolog, pem

How do I open a Pem file to check a) That the 'Not before' and 'Not after' dates are okay and b) That there is a chain of certs in the pem file to a route certificate authority?

I have tried:

```
:-use_module(library(http/http_client)).

url('http://fm4dd.com/openssl/source/PEM/certs/512b-rsa-example-cert.pem').

url_data(Url,D):-
 http_get(Url,D,[to(string)]).

url_data1(Url,Certificate):-
 http_get(Url,D,[to(stream(Stream))]),
 load_certificate(Stream, Certificate),
 close(Stream).
```

`url_data/1` works in that it returns the pem file as a string. But `url_data1/1` does not work. It is intended to return each certificate(s) as a list of terms.

*** Update ***

I have:

```
url_data1(Url,Certs):-
 http_open(Url,Stream,[]),
 all_certs(Stream,Certs),
 forall(member(C,Certs),my_validate(C)),
 close(Stream).

all_certs(Stream,[C1|Certs]):-
 catch(load_certificate(Stream,C1),_,fail),
 all_certs(Stream,Certs),!.
all_certs(_Stream,[]).

my_validate(C):-
 memberchk(to_be_signed(Signed),C),
 memberchk(key(Key),C),
 memberchk(signature(Signature),C),
 memberchk(signature_algorithm(A),C),
 algo_code(A,Code),
 rsa_verify(Key,Signed,Signature,[type(Code)]).

algo_code('RSA-SHA256',sha256).
algo_code('RSA-SHA1',sha1).
```

Which fails. What are the correct arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `http_open/3` in combination with `load_certificate/2`:

```
?- url(Url),
   http_open(Url, Stream, []),
   load_certificate(Stream, Certificate),
   maplist(portray_clause, Certificate).
```

Yielding:

```
version(0).
notbefore(1345613214).
notafter(1503293214).
serial('0DFA').
subject(['C'='JP', 'ST'='Tokyo', 'O'='Frank4DD', 'CN'='www.example.com']).
hash("071CB94F0CC8514D024124708EE8B2687BD7D9D5").
signature("14B64CBB817933E671A4DA516FCB081D8D60ECBC18C7734759B1F22048BB61FAFC4DAD898DD121EBD5D8E5BAD6A636FD745083B60FC71DDF7DE52E817F45E09FE23E79EED73031C72072D9582E2AFE125A3445A119087C89475F4A95BE23214A5372DA2A052F2EC970F65BFAFDDFB431B2C14A9C062543A1E6B41E7F869B1640").
signature_algorithm('RSA-SHA1').
etc.
```

Check the `issuer_name/1` element to obtain the issuer. You can use `load_certificate/2` again to read further certificates from the file.

Note that a much more typical way to validate the certificate chain is to establish a **secure connection** (via HTTPS), and then to use `ssl_peer_certificate/2` or `ssl_peer_certificate_chain/2` on the stream to obtain the peer certificate and certificate chain.

To validate the chain, you must verify the `signature/1` fields, which contain the digital signatures of the `to_be_signed/1` portions of the certificate, signed by the respective issuer.

You can use [**`library(crypto)`**](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=crypto) to verify the signatures.

Comment: Thanks once again for the knowledgeable answer.
I don't follow the section on validating the chain - If you cant tell I am a beginner with this! I assume I use `rsa_verify/4` with the option type set to what is found in the `signature_algorithm/1` term of each cert. But which how to enter the key, signature and data?  I will update my question with the code I have wrote and the error I am getting.

Comment: Please file a new question for verifying the certificate chain. Thank you!