# Verifying a signature chain SWI-Prolog

Tags: ssl, prolog, swi-prolog, pem

This question is related to [Opening and checking a Pem file in SWI-Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497172/opening-and-checking-a-pem-file-in-swi-prolog/44502468?noredirect=1#comment76007359_44502468)

Once I have downloaded and opened the certificates how do I verify the signature chain?
I have:

```
:-use_module(library(http/http_client)).

url('https://s3.amazonaws.com/echo.api/echo-api-cert-4.pem').

url_data1(Url,Certs):-
 http_open(Url,Stream,[]),
 all_certs(Stream,Certs),
 forall(member(C,Certs),my_validate(C)),
 close(Stream).

all_certs(Stream,[C1|Certs]):-
 catch(load_certificate(Stream,C1),_,fail),
 all_certs(Stream,Certs),!.
 all_certs(_Stream,[]).

my_validate(C):-
 memberchk(to_be_signed(Signed),C),
 memberchk(key(Key),C),
 memberchk(signature(Signature),C),
 memberchk(signature_algorithm(A),C),
 algo_code(A,Code),
 rsa_verify(Key,Signed,Signature,[type(Code)]).

algo_code('RSA-SHA256',sha256).
algo_code('RSA-SHA1',sha1).
```

This currently fails.

Comment: This is what you have, but what does it do or not do that is the problem?

Comment: The certificate "chain" consists only of a single certificate! Is this supposed to be self-signed? Otherwise, what is the public key of the issuer?

Comment: I was trying to use a demo pem file. I can not find one that contains a certificate chain. I have updated the question to a URL which I think currently presents a chain, but as I understand it this url may move or not present a chain at some time point in the future!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Preliminaries

Verifying digital signatures and entire certificate chains is extremely easy with Prolog.

However, you need to have a basic understanding of how certificates are signed. A **certificate chain** is a sequence of certificates C<sub>0</sub>, C<sub>1</sub>, ..., C<sub>N</sub>. I am using C<sub>N</sub> to denote the **root** certificate. Depending on the used convention, you may *mutatis mutandis* reverse the order of course.

Importantly, certificate C<sub>k</sub> is signed using the **private key** corresponding to the **public key** of C<sub>k**+1**</sub>.

Thus, one of the issues with your code is that you are mistakenly using the public key of C to verify the signature of C even though the certificate was signed with the private key corresponding to a *different* certificate.

A different issue stems from some confusion about *what* is being signed. We are signing the **hash** of the *to-be-signed* part of a certificate, not the data itself. Thus, we must verify the signature against that hash.

## Concrete example

To make this answer self-contained, I post here the relevant data from your use case, i.e., the relevant attributes of the certificates that the file contains at the time of this writing.

### Data

#### First certificate

From the first certificate in the chain, we need the **signature** and the **to-be-signed** portion, which are:

```
signature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
to_be_signed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
```

#### Second certificate

From the second certificate, we only need the **public key** to verify the signature that was issued for the previous certificate:

```
key(public_key(rsa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
```

### Verification

#### Computing the hash

As I said, a **hash** is what was actually signed. Critically, I don't mean the hash of the whole certificate, but the hash of the *to-be-signed* portion. This difference is important, because the hash of the whole certificate also comprises the signature, and that is of course not yet available when the certificate is being signed.

In SWI-Prolog, we can obtain the hash of the *to-be-signed* portion using [**`library(crypto)`**](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=crypto):

```
?- to_be_signed(TBS),
   hex_bytes(TBS, Bytes),
   crypto_data_hash(Bytes, Hash, [algorithm(sha256), encoding(octet)]).
TBS = "3082...EB3B62",
Bytes = [48, 130, 4, 102, 160, 3, 2, 1, 2|...],
Hash = '651bdcdd90251f71a47a5d1bbc6f28486c94d2dc3739dcd58ecb09b3f224ee05'.
```

I am using `sha256` because the first certificate indicates (`RSA` and) `SHA256` in its `signature_algorithm/1` field.

### Verifying the signature using CLP(FD) constraints

One of the easiest ways to verify an RSA signature is to use **CLP(FD) constraints**. We only need to compute Sig<sup>Exp</sup> mod *p*. We  plug in our concrete numbers, using `(#=)/2` to **evaluate** the arithmetic expression over integers:

```
?- X #= 0x7B86A6E7A86B192579380108B7EADA1C25E288AB46120117DC6A80635324C89713C70206EF3FE13CCA5EDFF43601972CB96658826ADCD68B0FB3AE7F5607D036D6AE8AF824CD96D7F1B4DB58E714343031F292B17E6EEF83872A0FD586CC0D1DA85A677E4AB4C6540E9132B5BC5644533E0388F830B1B6757B7DB88AB82846F08B3B6DCEC7F24319AB7EA56F86592DDDEC4522CAF331C8B81A4E543FBDBF4D661B534BAE546465DB88A525BC82A7B4127F0AFF4A55525927A66A09055743F109E30D90CA074D258166F0E472CB7CCDB0747ADE74F7040CFEEB9A78C3483864C5106D542556C874AF768005A6EC83ADEB2EE32F8E6F7182A362775C2BF40AFA20^0x010001
        mod 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
```

It yields:

```
X = 986236757547332986472011617696226561292849812918563355472727826767720188564083584387121625107510786855734801053524719833194566624465665316622563244215340671405971599343902468620306327831715457360719532421388780770165778156818229863337344187575566725786793391480600129482653072861971002459947277805295727097226389568776499707662505334062639449916265137796823793276300221537201727072401742985542559596685092673521228140822200236743113743661549252453726123450722876929538747702356573783116197523966334991563351853851212597377279504828784716104866621888265058037501385433453379649364782998949981722124880992983641605.
```

---

**Excursion**: On efficiency and use of CLP(FD).

You may now say: "Well, I don't really need `(#=)/2`, I can always use `(is)/2` which I learned decades ago." **But**, if you are using `(is)/2` in such examples, you easily end up with code that is **thousands of times less efficient**. As a simple benchmark, consider the predicate:

```
signature_pow(Sig, Exp, P, Pow) :-
        Pow #= Sig^Exp mod P.
```

Now we have, for the query:

```
?- time(signature_pow(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x010001, 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ow)).
```

the timing:

```
% 16 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (99% CPU, 130624 Lips)
```

In contrast, if we regress in Prolog language development and replace `(#=)/2` by `(is)/2`, we get:

```
% 3 inferences, 1.847 CPU in 1.852 seconds (100% CPU, 2 Lips)
```

**Reason**: In SWI-Prolog, certain goals involving `(#=)/2` *automatically* use specialized arithmetic predicates. You do not need to learn these predicates to use them. **CLP(FD) does it for you**.

**Recommendation**: Use CLP(FD) constraints for reasoning over *integers* in Prolog. They typically make your predicates more general, and sometimes *vastly* more efficient.  [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)

---

Now, what about `X`? To see what it is, consider its **hexadecimal** encoding:

```
?- format("~16r", [$X]).
 1fffffff...fff003031300d060960864801650304020105000420651bdcdd90251f71a47a5d1bbc6f28486c94d2dc3739dcd58ecb09b3f224ee05
```

This sounds familiar: At the end, you see that the **hash** of the *to-be-signed* portion of the certificate appears. This means that the signature checks out!

#### Verifying the signature with `rsa_verify/4`

Alternatively, we can use `rsa_verify/4` from `library(crypto)` to verify the signature.

Here is the full query:

```
?- to_be_signed(TBS),
   hex_bytes(TBS, Bytes),
   crypto_data_hash(Bytes, Hash, [algorithm(sha256), encoding(octet)]),
   signature(Sig),
   key(Key),
   rsa_verify(Key, Hash, Sig, [type(sha256)]).
```

Since this **succeeds**, we know that the **private key** corresponding to `Key` was used to produce the signature.

## Closing remarks

I have one important remark: *Normally*, this is all of course **completely unnecessary**!

The SWI-Prolog SSL infrastructure **automatically** verifies the certificate chain and thus all signatures every single time you use `http_open/3` and related predicates to make a connection via TLS. But it is interesting to make these calculations yourself. Sometimes it is even necessary, if, as in this example, you are reasoning over certificates you have stored somewhere.

One small additional remark: Please use `setup_call_cleanup/3` in your code. Otherwise, you risk leaking file descriptors if anything goes wrong before `close/1`, which is in fact even the case in your example.

Comment: What are these `"B2D805CA1..."` terms?

Comment: These are integers in *hexadecimal* encoding. Please remove the quotes and prepend `0x` to use them directly in Prolog queries and programs. For example: `?- X = 0xB2D805CA1.`, yielding: `X = 48008027297` in base 10.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Starting to get somewhere now!