# Verifying a signature chain SWI-Prolog 2- different in latest version of Swi?

Tags: ssl, prolog, swi-prolog, pem

Follow up from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44524628?noredirect=1

```
:-use_module(library(http/http_client)).
:-use_module(library(http/http_open)).
:-use_module(library(clpfd)).


url2('https://s3.amazonaws.com/echo.api/echo-api-cert-4.pem').

get_pem(Url,Certs):-
 setup_call_cleanup(
           http_open(Url,Stream,[]),
           ssl_peer_certificate_chain(Stream,Certs),
           close(Stream)
          ).

test(Key):-
 url2(U),
 get_pem(U,[A|Certs]),
 checkcertvalid_time(A),
 checkchain([A|Certs]),
 memberchk(key(Key),A).


 checkcertvalid_time(Acert):-
%what about The domain echo-api.amazon.com is present in the Subject   Alternative Names (SANs) section of the signing certificate
 memberchk(notbefore(NotBefore),Acert),
 memberchk(notafter(NotAfter),Acert),
 get_time(NowA),
 Now is round(NowA),
 Now #>NotBefore,
 Now #<NotAfter.

checkchain(Chain):-
 length(Chain,L),
 L#>1, %Insure chain has more than one cert
 checkchain_h(Chain).

checkchain_h([_]). %Reached the root.
checkchain_h([C1,C2|Rest]):-
 memberchk(signature(Sig),C1),
 memberchk(to_be_signed(Signed),C1),
 memberchk(key(Key),C2),
 hex_bytes(Signed,Bytes),
 crypto_data_hash(Bytes,Hash,[algorithm(sha256),encoding(octet)]),
 rsa_verify(Key,Hash,Sig,[type(sha256)]),
 checkchain_h([C2|Rest]).
```

If I call `test/1` then this code works in 7.5.3-1-g647ce9a but breaks in 7.5.9. In 7.5.9 `checkchain_h/1` fails when `memberchk(to_be_signed(Signed),C1)` is called.

This is tested on two separate computers not the same computer. Is there external software that might be causing this difference?

In addition as far as I know there should also be a field for 'subject_alternative_name' which I cant ever see.

Update:
On  7.5.9:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016

?- use_module(library(ssl)), current_prolog_flag(ssl_library_version, V).
 V = 'OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016'.
```

On 7.5.3-1-g647ce9a:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016

?- use_module(library(ssl)), current_prolog_flag(ssl_library_version, V).
V = 'OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016'.
```

Comment: Please add the output of `$ openssl version` for both systems, as well as that of the query: `?- use_module(library(ssl)), current_prolog_flag(ssl_library_version, V).`.

Comment: I have added that info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to the difference in the **OpenSSL library versions** that you are using.

Please see the documentation of [`load_certificate/2`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=load_certificate/2) for the fields that are currently made available in certificate structures, and under what conditions.

In particular:

> With **OpenSSL 1.0.2 and greater**, to_be_signed/1 is also available, yielding the hexadecimal representation of the TBS (to-be-signed) portion of the certificate.

For OpenSSL 1.0.1, which you are using on one of the machines, this field is *not* available.

As an aside, please note that OpenSSL 1.0.1 is [**no longer supported**](https://www.openssl.org/policies/releasestrat.html)! I strongly recommend you upgrade your installation of OpenSSL on *both* machines.

As to your other question, subject alternative names are currently not made available in certificate structures. They may of course become available in the future! Please keep an eye on the latest version of the SWI documentation to see what is currently available at any time.