# Read https body in SWI-Prolog

Tags: http, prolog, swi-prolog, alexa-skills-kit

Another question from me.. 
Overall I have been trying to define `authenticate_alexa/1`.

This (I think) is providing the same feature as this java code by amazon: https://github.com/amzn/alexa-skills-kit-java/blob/master/src/com/amazon/speech/speechlet/authentication/SpeechletRequestSignatureVerifier.java

The instructions for what this needs to do are at: https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/developing-an-alexa-skill-as-a-web-service

The problem I am now up to is that I need to read the full httpsbody request and find its hash value in order to verify it works with the key from the chain that we get.(Step 7 of validating the signature).

So I need to define `httpsbody/2` that will return the body exactly and then have the correct code for verifying the hash values.

My current code is :

```
alexa(Request):-
    authenticate_alexa(Request),
    %http_read_json_dict(Request,DictIn),
    %handle_dict(DictIn,DictOut),
    my_json_answer(hello,DictOut),
    reply_json(DictOut).

authenticate_alexa(Request):-
    check_sigchainurl(Request,URL),
    portray_clause(user_error,URL),
    get_certs(URL,[ACert|CertsRest]),
    checkcertvalid_time(ACert),
    checkchain([ACert|CertsRest]),
    memberchk(key(Key),ACert),
    base64decodesig_encryptedSig(Request,ESig),
%   httpsbody(Request,Body), %how do we read the body of the request?
        httpsbodybytes(Request,Body),
        portray_clause(user_error,'Http Body from httpsbody(Request,Body) :'),
        portray_clause(user_error,Body),
    crypto_data_hash(Body,Hash,[algorithm(sha1),encoding(octet)]),
    portray_clause(user_error,'Serviced signed Hash:'),
    portray_clause(user_error,Hash),
        atom_string(Hash,HashString),
    string_concat("0x",HashString,HashString2),
    number_string(HashNumber,HashString2),
    portray_clause(user_error,'Hash as Dec'),
    portray_clause(user_error,HashNumber),

    signature_pow(ESig,0x010001,Key,ClpfdHash),
    portray_clause(user_error,'clpfdhash:'),
    portray_clause(user_error,ClpfdHash),
        %rsa_verify(Key,Hash,ESig,[type(sha1)]),
    portray_clause(user_error,done).

get_certs(URL,Certs):-
   setup_call_cleanup(
        http_open(URL,Stream,[]),
        ssl_peer_certificate_chain(Stream,Certs),
        close(Stream)
          ).

signature_pow(Sig, Exp, P, Pow) :-
        portray_clause(user_error,'ESig:'),
    portray_clause(user_error,Sig),
    (atom(Sig) -> portray_clause(user_error,'it is an atom');portray_clause(user_error,'it is not an atom')),
    (number(Sig) -> portray_clause(user_error,'it is a number');portray_clause(user_error,'it is not a number')),
    atom_string(Sig,Sigstring),
    string_concat("0x",Sigstring,SigString2),
    number_string(SigNumber,SigString2),
    portray_clause(user_error,'Exp:'),
    portray_clause(user_error,Exp),
    portray_clause(user_error,'P:'),
    portray_clause(user_error,P),
    P =public_key(rsa(P2,EXP2,_,_,_,_,_,_)),
    portray_clause(user_error,'P just number:'),
        portray_clause(user_error,P2),
    (string(P2) -> portray_clause(user_error,'String hex P number');portray_clause(user_error,notstring)),
    string_concat("0x",P2,NewString),
    portray_clause(user_error,NewString),
    number_string(P3,NewString),
    portray_clause(user_error,'P number as dec:'),
    portray_clause(user_error,P3),  
        Pow #= SigNumber^Exp mod P3,
    portray_clause(user_error,'Pow'),
    portray_clause(user_error,Pow),
    portray_clause(user_error,verified).

check_sigchainurl(Request,URL):-
    memberchk(signaturecertchainurl(URL),Request),
    parse_url(URL,P), %what about normalise url? I dont think it is needed
    memberchk(protocol(https),P),%should make case insenstive
    memberchk(host('s3.amazonaws.com'),P), %should make case insenstive
    memberchk(path(Path),P),
    string_concat('/echo.api/',_,Path),
    (memberchk(port(Port),P) -> Port =443 ; true).

checkcertvalid_time(Acert):-
    memberchk(notbefore(NotBefore),Acert),
    memberchk(notafter(NotAfter),Acert),
    get_time(NowA),
    Now is round(NowA),
    Now #>NotBefore,
    Now #<NotAfter.

checkchain(Chain):-
        length(Chain,L),
    L#>1.           %Insure chain has more than one cert
    %portray_clause(user_error,Chain),
    checkchain_h(Chain).

checkchain_h([_]). %Reached the root.
checkchain_h(Chain):-
        Chain =[C1,C2|Rest],
        memberchk(signature(Sig),C1),
    memberchk(to_be_signed(Signed),C1),
    memberchk(key(Key),C2),
    hex_bytes(Signed,Bytes),
    crypto_data_hash(Bytes,Hash,[algorithm(sha256),encoding(octet)]),
    rsa_verify(Key,Hash,Sig,[type(sha256)]),
    checkchain_h([C2|Rest]).

base64decodesig_encryptedSig(Request,Hex):-
    memberchk(signature(B64Sig),Request),
    portray_clause(user_error,'base64 encoded sig:'),
    portray_clause(user_error,B64Sig),
    base64(ESig,B64Sig),
    atom_codes(ESig,Bytes),
    hex_bytes(Hex,Bytes).
    %portray_clause(user_error,'Esig is base64 sig decoded using base64//2:'),
    %portray_clause(user_error,ESig).
        %portray_clause(user_error,'Can not print esig').

httpsbodybytes(Request,BodyBytes2):-
    memberchk(input(In),Request),
    portray_clause(user_error,"Bytes:"),
    mygetbody2(In,BodyBytes,0),
    list_butlast(BodyBytes,BodyBytes2).

mygetbody2(_Stream,[],-1).
mygetbody2(Stream,[Byte|Bytes],Check):-
    dif(Check,-1),
    get_byte(Stream,Byte),
    %portray_clause(user_error,Byte),
    mygetbody2(Stream,Bytes,Byte).

list_butlast([X|Xs], Ys) :-                 % use auxiliary predicate ...
   list_butlast_prev(Xs, Ys, X).            % ... which lags behind by one item

list_butlast_prev([], [], _).
list_butlast_prev([X1|Xs], [X0|Ys], X0) :-  
   list_butlast_prev(Xs, Ys, X1).
```

Which upon receiving a request outputs:

```
'https://s3.amazonaws.com/echo.api/echo-api-cert-4.pem'.
'base64 encoded sig:'.
'Nu2v3C8hWNSF7G7N/B5WWqFnhuGMPJeMGi76FanbF8D4so+AiRSWVaehPXoaiLZpCiEb5Ysd+QFCBEt5/5a6MoLh4JTAhwGcnGUs+GbZo7rkk12t6meUTldnBNZ4/1boUNGurWCmPy1pkCWyHIt7udWj2zCdHx+4cFCKy8GVWfjOtZ3n52LWzGd+HO0RF0GQ25cSoFQGr2I5bT060Bodt3PrZob/nWnPxqayC+y53Itt/I0YUtM2QnPYByx/GJuyzMUuA0/v0PH15oGOE+wwYszr1C6mmEKMRdkCzFEO6z4kuw6UeXDaECS9ak04XCp+gsYkHQjJYpoB3s8T6qeNGQ=='.
"Bytes:".
'Http Body from httpsbody(Request,Body) :'.
[123, 34, 118, 101, 114, 115, 105, 111, 110, 34, 58, 34, 49, 46, 48, 34, 44, 34, 115, 101, 115, 115, 105, 111, 110, 34, 58, 123, 34, 110, 101, 119, 34, 58, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 44, 34, 115, 101, 115, 115, 105, 111, 110, 73, 100, 34, 58, 34, 83, 101, 115, 115, 105, 111, 110, 73, 100, 46, 99, 55, 99, 54, 49, 55, 51, 100, 45, 98, 98, 102, 52, 45, 52, 56, 57, 101, 45, 97, 48, 98, 97, 45, 52, 54, 55, 102, 101, 56, 48, 51, 100, 97, 101, 99, 34, 44, 34, 97, 112, 112, 108, 105, 99, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 34, 58, 123, 34, 97, 112, 112, 108, 105, 99, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 73, 100, 34, 58, 34, 97, 109, 122, 110, 49, 46, 97, 115, 107, 46, 115, 107, 105, 108, 108, 46, 97, 50, 55, 101, 98, 53, 48, 53, 45, 102, 99, 101, 102, 45, 52, 57, 98, 102, 45, 56, 57, 55, 53, 45, 51, 101, 49, 97, 54, 100, 55, 98, 55, 99, 55, 52, 34, 125, 44, 34, 97, 116, 116, 114, 105, 98, 117, 116, 101, 115, 34, 58, 123, 125, 44, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 34, 58, 123, 34, 117, 115, 101, 114, 73, 100, 34, 58, 34, 97, 109, 122, 110, 49, 46, 97, 115, 107, 46, 97, 99, 99, 111, 117, 110, 116, 46, 65, 71, 77, 77, 80, 53, 85, 81, 73, 81, 80, 89, 52, 69, 75, 90, 90, 72, 88, 71, 68, 52, 86, 72, 55, 89, 72, 80, 55, 88, 65, 51, 54, 84, 65, 79, 50, 82, 54, 76, 87, 79, 77, 89, 73, 88, 75, 78, 52, 68, 72, 88, 88, 51, 66, 73, 83, 53, 87, 83, 82, 78, 84, 53, 65, 55, 86, 79, 75, 86, 82, 76, 50, 77, 75, 65, 78, 77, 86, 51, 75, 50, 68, 77, 79, 66, 50, 87, 75, 85, 68, 84, 72, 73, 74, 86, 87, 73, 77, 83, 65, 51, 76, 81, 75, 82, 73, 73, 83, 72, 71, 55, 80, 71, 55, 77, 89, 70, 65, 53, 50, 72, 77, 73, 67, 81, 87, 53, 53, 76, 50, 73, 90, 65, 76, 70, 90, 80, 77, 82, 54, 67, 74, 83, 74, 54, 74, 55, 90, 82, 75, 54, 54, 77, 87, 82, 55, 66, 89, 88, 69, 76, 66, 73, 50, 75, 79, 69, 90, 81, 73, 72, 68, 88, 79, 72, 72, 90, 70, 71, 90, 50, 81, 83, 90, 82, 87, 52, 75, 55, 79, 55, 53, 82, 50, 89, 88, 74, 54, 85, 87, 65, 86, 70, 77, 53, 65, 34, 125, 125, 44, 34, 114, 101, 113, 117, 101, 115, 116, 34, 58, 123, 34, 116, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 34, 73, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 82, 101, 113, 117, 101, 115, 116, 34, 44, 34, 114, 101, 113, 117, 101, 115, 116, 73, 100, 34, 58, 34, 69, 100, 119, 82, 101, 113, 117, 101, 115, 116, 73, 100, 46, 101, 54, 98, 56, 102, 101, 101, 100, 45, 101, 99, 101, 51, 45, 52, 101, 97, 97, 45, 97, 102, 50, 100, 45, 99, 52, 55, 102, 54, 53, 55, 53, 57, 50, 49, 54, 34, 44, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 115, 116, 97, 109, 112, 34, 58, 34, 50, 48, 49, 55, 45, 48, 54, 45, 49, 57, 84, 48, 57, 58, 52, 54, 58, 51, 53, 90, 34, 44, 34, 108, 111, 99, 97, 108, 101, 34, 58, 34, 101, 110, 45, 71, 66, 34, 44, 34, 105, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 34, 58, 123, 34, 110, 97, 109, 101, 34, 58, 34, 103, 101, 116, 65, 78, 101, 119, 70, 97, 99, 116, 34, 125, 125, 125].
'Serviced signed Hash:'.
'64f1329a1f707809174ee50a6df9f65099bba371'.
'Hash as Dec'.
576277964734800966164187927075551858658582963057.
'ESig:'.
'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'.
'it is an atom'.
'it is not a number'.
'Exp:'.
65537.
'String hex P number'.
'P number as dec:'.
23367091749731801702903258951332579149824717752403036738901918995576378221876991769215986117060832205938888292020670601919717320529579897428555756633750717630113812467159229456710215094841206836055184753491046351652384568208399197333334554354625485949013821994244854426626217946383766717620084958916568639573896625634280251135248126961353512501885364402868885624724204807768627558428281558589460261611023934365963620820837651899784648073096603839587883308136461448176498481934437054583664797923342609641294880521414948881981392762983173267396409953920339084175033120756130451537931813023420728016059287928243275252817.
'Pow'.
12996685404671854237337597057543403676067050401691031855263389356566563793267812208256044577937494803172529297811694697178075070962940655950099948830185429064594023055861430145065585159411714852185690089480769442404348006975883315459440182824265725834630838968686976962484449232569444592352993640898180649431183234665232203068528805991370779087967630073792656438871568328046165107095895856647485355472888016164031315511155737623289424119686691313121050647697592969024984185347837785283636035540443593041046047481149874499335289745021686457982828945403796990195913021023926745047308779421759663632404133499645864797253.
verified.
'clpfdhash:'.
12996685404671854237337597057543403676067050401691031855263389356566563793267812208256044577937494803172529297811694697178075070962940655950099948830185429064594023055861430145065585159411714852185690089480769442404348006975883315459440182824265725834630838968686976962484449232569444592352993640898180649431183234665232203068528805991370779087967630073792656438871568328046165107095895856647485355472888016164031315511155737623289424119686691313121050647697592969024984185347837785283636035540443593041046047481149874499335289745021686457982828945403796990195913021023926745047308779421759663632404133499645864797253.
done.
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The two hash values are not the same. So it is currently not working.

Answer (score 2):

**Tentative answer**:

I think you are on the right track with `read_string/3`, but you need to break this down to a more manageable case so that others have a chance to help. For example, please add to your question:

- the full HTTPS body you have received
- the hash *you* have calculated for it
- the hash that *the service* has signed for it.

I have explained how to obtain the hash that was signed in:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44524628/1613573

Please see the CLP(FD)-based calculation.

Please note that at the time the connection is established (via TLS), this is purely an issue of the **HTTP** (not HTTPS) layer.

**Useful predicates**:

I see you are also wrestling with reasoning about the actual Base64-encoded signature. To make sense of this, you can apply the following steps:

- use `base64/2` to obtain the plain **atom**, i.e., `base64(Plain, Encoded)`
- use `atom_codes/2` to obtain a list of **codes** that represent the atom, i.e., `atom_codes(Plain, Bytes)`
- use [**`hex_bytes/2`**](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=hex_bytes/2) from `library(crypto)` to obtain the **hex encoding** of the signature, i.e., `hex_bytes(Hex, Bytes)`.

Thus, you obtain with a usable *hexadecimal* representation of the signature. You can use this for further computations, using CLP(FD) constraints or `rsa_verify/4`.

I have tried these calculations with your example, and I get for `Pow #= Sig^Exp mod M` an integer that ends with:

```
b2feb64cd1ae11365f8917b71bb751142b63f159e12c02a1720b78958c3e7f7e
```

in hexadecimal notation. This is *not* the hash you calculated. Therefore, there may be a problem with the encoding you are using to calculate your own hash of the data to verify the signature. Please see the values for `crypto_data_hash/3`. In particular, I recommend `crypto_data_hash(Bytes, Hash, [encoding(bytes)])`, where you must ensure that `Bytes` is the actual list of *bytes* that represents the transmitted data.

Comment: I am not sure I follow the clp(fd) calculation. I understand: Instead of using `rsa_verify/4` in`authenticate_alexa/1` I should use 
 `signature_pow(Sig,Exp,P,Pow)` with Sig=ESig and P is the Key what value is Exp? `0x010001`?  then `Pow` is the calculated hash? But Esig is the plain text of the base64 signature.. and this is a set of weird characters that dont print to the screen well.. not a number as far I can tell. Will update question with some outputs.

Comment: The output is too unstructured to tell what exactly is happening. Please use `portray_clause/1` or the `"~q"` format modifier to emit valid Prolog terms that can be processed with Prolog. Other than that, it appears that the hash that was signed is exactly identical to the hash that you computed yourself. This means that the signature is valid.

Comment: I have tried to make it clearer by updating the code and showing the output with portray clause.. as far as I am aware I have not computed the hash!

Comment: Thanks for the pointers... It seems to make more sense now apart from the hash values not matching!  I have updated the code in the question to read bytes and then used `crypto_data_hash` with encoding as `octet` rather than `bytes` ? If you can see anything clearly wrong then it would be good to know! Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Yes, I meant `encoding(octet)` of course. You can make the code easier to maintain by using the `~q` format modifier. For example: `format("Pow = ~q", [Pow])`. Other than that, I recommend you emit the hexadecimal encoding of the computed numbers, using the `~16r` format modifier. If the signature is valid, then the end of the power in hexadecimal representation should match the hash you computed for the HTTP body.  One additional method you could try is to download the validation code that Amazon provide, and compare the computed hashes and received bytes with those of your program.